# Capitalize all letters with first one bigger

Tags: css

what's the most efficient way to do this in CSS???
Basically it looks like this: {F}IRST {L}ETTER, where the letters in the braces are a little bigger than the other ones but they all the letters are uppercase.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [font-variant](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-variant.asp) property of CSS

```css
h1 {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.simplyCapFirstBigger
{
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

Comment: Cheers buddy! :)

Answer (score 2):

```css
p {
  text-transform: uppercase
}

p::first-letter {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<p>Example text</p>
```

[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/ciyolulake/edit?html,css,output)

[Browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-first-letter)

Comment: Cheers buddy! :)

Answer (score 0):

Look if it is no dynamic data i have a good suggestion which is:
wrap the letters you want it to be slightly bigger in a span and create a class for this span with font size bigger a than the h1 font size for example if h1 font size 16px make the span 18px

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

span {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>M</span>ain <span>H</span>eading</h1>
```

simply this will solve your problem easily but using css font-variant doesn't take size.

Comment: Cheers buddy! :)